# Kafka Connect API error when set default value of STRUCT type

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to set a default value of `STRUCT`, the code is shown below:

```
        SchemaBuilder schemaBuilder = SchemaBuilder.struct().name("homeAddress")
                .field("province", SchemaBuilder.STRING_SCHEMA)
                .field("city", SchemaBuilder.STRING_SCHEMA);
        Struct defaultValue = new Struct(schemaBuilder.build())
                .put("province", "aaaa")
                .put("city", "bbbb");
        Schema dataSchema = SchemaBuilder.struct().name("personMessage")
                .field("address", schemaBuilder.defaultValue(defaultValue).build()).build();
        Struct struct = new Struct(dataSchema);
```

but I got error as below

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.SchemaBuilderException: Invalid default value
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.SchemaBuilder.defaultValue(SchemaBuilder.java:131)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Struct schemas do not match.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.ConnectSchema.validateValue(ConnectSchema.java:251)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.ConnectSchema.validateValue(ConnectSchema.java:213)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.SchemaBuilder.defaultValue(SchemaBuilder.java:129)
    ... 1 more
```

I digged code of ConnectSchema.validateValue and found why throws exception,

type of schema of value is ConnectSchema, but another is SchemaBuilder, then throw exception.

```
case STRUCT:
    Struct struct = (Struct) value;
    if (!struct.schema().equals(schema))
        throw new DataException("Struct schemas do not match.");
    struct.validate();
```

method of equals

```
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ConnectSchema schema = (ConnectSchema) o;
        return Objects.equals(optional, schema.optional) &&
                Objects.equals(version, schema.version) &&
                Objects.equals(name, schema.name) &&
                Objects.equals(doc, schema.doc) &&
                Objects.equals(type, schema.type) &&
                Objects.deepEquals(defaultValue, schema.defaultValue) &&
                Objects.equals(fields, schema.fields) &&
                Objects.equals(keySchema, schema.keySchema) &&
                Objects.equals(valueSchema, schema.valueSchema) &&
                Objects.equals(parameters, schema.parameters);
```

Can anyone help how to set default value of Type `STRUCT`

below is code of method 'defaultValue':

```
public SchemaBuilder defaultValue(Object value) {
        checkCanSet(DEFAULT_FIELD, defaultValue, value);
        checkNotNull(TYPE_FIELD, type, DEFAULT_FIELD);
        try {
            ConnectSchema.validateValue(this, value);
        } catch (DataException e) {
            throw new SchemaBuilderException("Invalid default value", e);
        }
        defaultValue = value;
        return this;
    }
```

seems will be ok if i change ConnectSchema.validateValue(this, value) to ConnectSchema.validateValue(this.builder(), value), i dont know if it's ok for other case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this 
`Struct defaultValue = new Struct(schemaBuilder.build())` to
`Struct defaultValue = new Struct(schemaBuilder)`

`ConnectSchema` and `SchemaBuilder` both class are implementing `Schema` `schemaBuilder.schemaBuilder.build()` is passing all values to `ConnectSchema` constructor and return new `Schema` object and this object is immutable.

Look at this.

```
System.out.println(struct); //empty 
System.out.println(struct.get("address"));  //default values
System.out.println(  ((Struct)struct.get("address")).getString("city")   ); //default values
System.out.println(  ((Struct)struct.get("address")).getString("province")   ); //default values
```

Default values are not rewrited to struct fields. They exist only in schema definition and if filed is empty the default value is returned from schema definition.

From Struct.class

```
  public Object get(Field field) {
        Object val = this.values[field.index()];
        if (val == null && field.schema().defaultValue() != null) {
            val = field.schema().defaultValue();
        }

        return val;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks your response. i'm following your suggestion, but the object of struct is empty. i add system.out.printlin(struct.toString()) at last line, then output is "Struct{}"

Comment: i think default value only can be set at creation of schema, dont know if it is right.

Comment: I was pretty sure you will ask about this empty Struct{} . More explanation in answer.

Comment: understand, test passed, million thanks for your help.

Comment: hi @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz, when i am using that solution, and send record with JsonConvertor, i get another error. i open a new discussion.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729574/kafka-connect-api-error-when-send-default-value-of-struct-with-both-jsonconverto, thanks for help.